# mobile solution for .entwine onclick: function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which opens and closes a comment form. This works well at normal screens (desktop, notebook) but not on mobile devices. I tried already with on('click touchstart', function() but I'm not sure how to do this in combination with .entwine:

```
        $( ".comment-reply-link" ).entwine({
        onclick: function( e ) {
            var allForms = $( ".comment-reply-form-holder" ),
                formID = $( this ).prop('href').replace(/^[^#]*#/, '#'),
                form = $(formID).closest('.comment-reply-form-holder');

            // Prevent focus
            e.preventDefault();
            if(form.is(':visible')) {
                allForms.slideUp();
            } else {
                allForms.not(form).slideUp();
                form.slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add more details of the problem? I don't see a reason why you wouldn't be able to just define both onclick and ontouchstart in the entwine function, one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

This was an issue with jQuery. In the mobile version I use jQuery 2.2.4 which doesn't support browser detection anymore. With a plugin for browser detection it works well (https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin).

Thanks for the replies anyway!